# run next tasks in dag if another dag is complete

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver

dag1:

```
start >> clean >> end
```

I have a dag where i run a few tasks. But I want to modify it such that the `clean` steps only runs if another dag "dag2" is not running at the moment.

Is there any way I can import information regarding my "dag2", check its status and if it is in success mode, I can proceed to the `clean` step
Something like this:

```
start >> wait_for_dag2 >> clean >> end
```

How can I achieve the `wait_for_dag2` part?

Comment: you can use ExternalTaskSensor https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/external_task_sensor.html

Answer (score 2):

There are some different answers depends on what you want to do:

- if you have two dags with the same schedule interval, and you want to make the run of second dag waits the **same run** of first one, you can use [ExternalTaskSensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/external_task_sensor.html) on the last task of the first dag
- if you want to run a dag2, after each run of a dag1 even if it's triggered manually, in this case you need to update dag1 and add a [TriggerDagRunOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/trigger_dagrun/index.html#airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun.TriggerDagRunOperator) and set schedule interval of the second to `None`
- > I want to modify it such that the clean steps only runs if another dag "dag2" is not running at the moment.

  if you have two dags and you don't want to run them in same time to avoid a conflict on an external server/service, you can use one of the first two propositions or just use higher priority for the task of the first dag, and use the same pool (with 1 slot) for the tasks which lead to the conflict, but you will lose the parallelism on these tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Hossein's Approach is the way people usually go. However if you want to get info about any dag run data, you can use the airlfow functionality to get that info. The following appraoch is good when you do not want(or are not allowed) to modify another dag:

```
from airflow.models.dagrun import DagRun
from airflow.utils.state import DagRunState

dag_runs = DagRun.find(dag_id='the_dag_id_you_want_to_check')
last_run = dag_runs[-1]
if last_run.state == DagRunState.SUCCESS:
    print('the dag run was successfull!')
else:
    print('the dag state is -->: ', last_run.state)
```